# Return Constant dynamic JNI data to Java object while application is running

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, jnienv

So I have this program where i constantly retrieves data from my JNI function (in C++) when the application is running I retrieve these data in the JNI function
but I want to pass the data to my Java class which handles these inputs values (for instance x and y values).

How am I supposed to pass the data to the Java class constantly while the application is running?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is running? A loop?

Comment: Yes there is a loop in the JNI function which returns the data

Comment: So what have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  You appear to have a loop to call this method and it returns new data each time.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a Java application that calls a function in a JNI library and the function in turn starts a second thread that needs to send data back to Java regularly?

Assuming this is the case:

Option 1 is the [invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html): `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` will give you a handle to the existing VM and you can go on from there. You attach your new thread, then you can either call static methods (`FindClass`/`GetStaticMethodID`/`Call<type>Method`) or you can call methods in an object (`GetObjectClass`/`GetMethodID`/`Call<type>Method`). You would have to pass the object from Java in a previous call and keep it in a global reference.

Option 2 is [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna): if your library doesn't have to be a JNI library for some other reason, you can make it a "regular" library and call it via JNA. JNA supports passing function pointers to native functions via the `Callback` class. You can then call this callback from your new thread.